# Usage of article with "one more"

Tags: articles, zero-article

Can we use an article before "one more"?
For example:
"Please give me ***a*** one more coffee."
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No you can't, because ***a = an = one***, and even though you want another one, that doesn't justify adding another version of the same article.

Comment: I also thought about that, but wanted to hear an opinion of someone much more experienced than me. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: In linguistic terminology, you could say that _one more_ is a determiner, and so is _a_, and you can't have two determiners in the single slot available. In English, noun phrases are `Determiner` + `Adjectives` + `Head Noun` + `Adjuncts`, which is why *_the my brother_ is ungrammatical, too -- _the_ and _my_ are both determiners.

Comment: @JohnLawler How about *Please give me one more coffee and **the two** pastries on that tray*?

Comment: _The_ and _two_ can combine -- determiner + quantifier -- but it gets complicated fast when you realize that all of them can be phrases or even clauses and still behave as one constituent. Like _a few of the what I had considered at the time to be hundreds, but in fact turned out to be only dozens of eggs that were thrown at him_, which is a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ordinary, everyday English, a native speaker would not say '*Give me a one more coffee'.

Instead, he or she would say

'Give me one more coffee'

or

'Give me another coffee'.

*One more* can be considered a [determiner](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/what/what-is-a-determiner.html)  and usually a noun phrase utilizes only one determiner. The indefinite article *a* is also a determiner, so combining *a* with *one more* results in  two determiners.